# ASP.NET Request QueryString says value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this link here...

`<li><a href="/?fileDownloadable=downloadableProducts/MyPDF.pdf" target="_blank" runat="server">MyPDF</a></li>`

and in my code behind I try to a Request.QueryString["fileDownloadable"] and it says it returning null...which in the link its not..

Any Ideas?

Comment: please check if have escaped the "/" in your link, it is a reserved character. The escape sequence is %2F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a "." in front of the slash or remove the slash

```
<a href="./?fileDownloadable=downloadableProducts/MyPDF.pdf" target="_blank" runat="server">MyPDF</a>

OR

<a href="?fileDownloadable=downloadableProducts/MyPDF.pdf" target="_blank" runat="server">MyPDF</a>
```

Note: this would reference/redirect the current page. Is that what you want?